# rewriting the URLs dynamically laravel

Tags: laravel, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite some of the pages URL in my web app, for example, I have a company details page and I want the URL of this page to contain the name of the company without space or special characters and to have the id too, and I have no idea on how to do that or where to start.

I tried adding the name of the company in the route as a parameter like this:

```
Route::get('/{RS}-{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@getDetails')->name('details');
```

It didn't work for some reason and even if it worked there's no way to replace the special characters with their normal form and replace the space with dashes.

This the URL I'm getting: http://mywebsite.come/entreprise_details-13109

this the URL I want: http://mywebsite.come/yoorika-managements-13109 ( with Yoorika Managements being the name of the company )

I searched a lot but I can't seem to find what I am looking for, I just need someone to help me find the right term.  thank you!

Comment: Regarding your comment: `it didn't work for some reason and even if it worked there's no way to replace the special characters with their normal form and replace the space with dashes .` that does exist, it is called `slugging`. See the [Str helper functions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-slug). Consider adding a `slug` column on your model, that contains the unique slug. You can override `getRouteKeyName()` on your model to use it for route model binding. Here is a [package of the company Spatie](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable) that adds unique slug for model.

Comment: @EricLandheer let's say i used the slug and i got the string i want .. how do i add it to the route ??

Comment: You can use [Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding) for this. Basically, you pass your model name between brackets: `Route::get('/{company}', 'SiteController@getDetails')->name('details');`. If you set the `getRouteKeyName()` in your model to your slugged attribute instead of ID, Laravel tries to find the model by the given slug in the URL. You do not necessairly have to use the `getRouteKeyName()` function, you can also set the attribute in your like so `{company:slug}` (if `slug` is the attribute that contains the slug).

Comment: @EricLandheer this method will work for the newly added companies because i need to add a new column and fill it with the slug every time a new company is added to the table, what about the companies that are already in the table because i have like 13K companies and it would be really tiring to change them all again !

Comment: You could create a seeder or command that generates a slug for them. Just make sure the attribute is unique for every company. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @EricLandheer i will try it and see if it works, thank you so much

Comment: @EricLandheer i tried using this :

<h6 class="card-title"><a href="{{route('details',['RS'=>Str::slug($Resultas->RS , '-') ,'id'=> $Resultas->ID] )}}">{{$Resultas->RS}}</a></h6>

but i am getting the missing required parameter error

Comment: @EricLandheer it worked by using the method i just showed you i just had to add ? the RS in the route like this : Route::get('/{RS?}-{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@getDetails')->name('details');

Comment: Consider combining `RS` and `id` into a new attribute. So make a migration, add a text `slug` attribute with `unique()` constraint. Then you can simply use `route model binding` as explained earlier.

Comment: @EricLandheer i will try it for sure, just one question please .
now that i changed my route and added the slug string  everything works fine but the increment function that i was using to count views it just says that the function can't work on null but the views column isn't empty ... any idea ?

Comment: Are you using a reference to the `details` route somewhere in your increment function? If so, you should update the implementation of that route in the function.

Comment: @EricLandheer no this is where i am using the increment function : 

public function getDetails($id)
    {
        $detailsPage = entreprise::find($id);
        $detailsPage->increment('views');
  }

Comment: Does `detailsPage` exist? I believe since you updated the route parameters, it will not find the right `Enterprise` anymore. This is why you should use `route model binding` and add an extra column to identify the right `Enterprise`.

Comment: @EricLandheer sorry to bother you again, i used the sluggable eloquent package and now i am able to slug the titles and get them in my URL and everything is working perfectly .. i just now need to slug all the previous data in my database and you suggested to use seeder but i don't know what is that !

Comment: Great! Documentation about seeders can be found in the [Laravel docs](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable). Create a seeder `php artisan make:seeder IndvidiualSeederName` or whatever name you want to use. Add similar code to the `run()` function to do something like:  `Enterprise::whereNull('slugged_column_name')->each->save()`. Or perhaps `update()`. This should automatically trigger the slugged field to be set. You can run this indvidiual seeder like: `php artisan db:seed --class"IndvidiualSeederName"`. If you run into a problem, consider opening a new question.

Answer (score 1):

In route :

```
Route::get('/{input}', 'App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@getDetails')->name('details');
```

In controller :

```
public function getDetails($input)
{
   $input_array = explode("-", $input);
   $name = $input_array[0];
   $id = $input_array[1];

   $data = MyModel::where('id', $id)->get();
   // return data to view 
}
```

In list view, you may display data like this (table cell ) :

```
<td> <a href="/{{name .'-'.{{id}}"> {{name .'-'.{{id}}<td/>
```